# Delay Loading Highcharts' Chart

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, webiopi

I was wondering if there was a way of delaying the loading of a Highcharts' chart on page load. At the moment my chart is loading as soon as the page opens which is causing my code to crash as the script has not had enough time to fetch the data for the chart.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: If you load data from external source, you should initialize chart in the callback of function which do it.

Comment: If I do this then I get the error "TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function" Highcharts is definitely initialised correctly as I have seen it working before.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo.

Comment: You can do that on the jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways of doing this. One is to initialise the chart when you receive the data (example using jQuery post, data looks like [5,6,8,11]):

```
$(function(){
    $.post('test_highchart.asp', {actn:'load-data'}, function(dat){
        $('#chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Delayed Loading'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Values'
                }
            },
            series:[{
                name: 'value',
                data: dat
            }]
        });
    }, 'json');
});
```

Or you can initialise the chart on load then pump the data into the chart when you get it (again data looks like [5,6,8,11]):

```
$(function(){
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Delayed Loading'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            }
        },
        series:[{
            name: 'values',
            id: 'series1',
            data: []
        }]
    });

    // load data:
    $.post('test_highchart.asp', {actn:'load-data'}, function(dat){
        $.each(dat, function (val) {
            // add points to chart:
            window.chart.get('series1').addPoint(val);
        });
    }, 'json');
});
```

check http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data for details.

cheers